# how to get nsDictionary element by using for-in

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"one":@"1",@"two":@"2"};

for (NSDictionary* tmp in myDict) {
    NSLog(@"%@",tmp);
}
```

resut:
[image]

my `tmp`is NSString

I want to get a `dictionary` with `key`= one , `value` = 1

Comment: `for (Class *varClass in aDict)` will iterate the keys. So for `(NSString *aKey in myDict){NSLog(@"Key %@, value %@", aKey, [myDict objectForKey:aKey]);}`

Comment: Are you really looking to have `NSArray *stuff = @[ @{ @"one" : @"1" }, @{ @"two" : @"2" } ];` ? Or maybe you want to use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`

Comment: Nine9 you can use my code.It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for in` for `NSDictionary` will iterate the keys.

```
for (NSString * key in myDict) {
    NSLog(@"%@",key);
    NSString * value = [myDict objectForKey:key];
}
```

If you want to get a dictionary. You have to create a dictionary from these values

```
for (NSString * key in myDict) {
    NSLog(@"%@",key);
    NSString * value = [myDict objectForKey:key];
    NSDictionary * dict = @{key:value};
}
```

Or you should init like this:

```
   NSArray *arrDict = @[{@{"one":@"1"},@{@"two":@"2"}];
   for (NSDictionary* tmp in arrDict) {
      NSLog(@"%@",tmp);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys from your dic then add the key and value to your new dic like this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"one":@"1",@"two":@"2"};
NSArray *keys = [myDict allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSDictionary *yourDic = @{key: [myDict valueForKey:key]};
    NSLog(@"%@", yourDic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create it that way. If you wanted to have  a `NSDictionary` inside another `NSDictionary` you should write something like this :

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{
    @"firstDict" : @{
        @"one":@"1"
    },
    @"secondDict": @{
        @"two":@"2"
    }
};
```

Above code will create a `NSDictionary` with two dictionaries at keys `@firstDict` and `@secondDict`.

Also, bear in mind, that because dictionaries are key-value pairs, using a `for-in` loop, actually loops through the keys in that dictionary. So your code is equivalent to:

```
for(NSString *key in dict.allKeys) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"one":@"1",@"two":@"2"};
NSMutableArray *arrayObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrayKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrayObjectKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (NSString *stringValue in myDict.allValues)
{
  [arrayObject addObject:stringValue];
}
for (NSString *stringKey in myDict.allKeys)
{
  [arrayKey addObject:stringKey];
}
for(int i = 0;i<[arrayKey count];i++)
{
    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayKey objectAtIndex:i]],@"key",nil];
   [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayObject objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:@"value"];

   [arrayObjectKey addObject:dict];
}
NSLog(@"The arrayObjectKey is - %@",arrayObjectKey);
```

The Output is

```
The arrayObjectKey is -
(
    {
    key = one;
    value = 1;
},
    {
    key = two;
    value = 2;
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"One",@"2","Two",nil];
```

Get a value out using:(this example tmp will be 1)

```
NSString *tmp = [myDict objectForKey:@"One"];
```

Display the output in console:

```
NSLog(@"%@",tmp);
```

To display the whole NSDictionary

```
NSLog (@"contents of myDict: %@",myDict);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is creating a dictionary with key-value pairs. I think what you want to do is have an array with dictionaries.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@"one":@"1"}, @{@"two":@"2"}];
for (NSDictionary* tmp in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@",tmp);
}
```

However I don't see a point in doing this. What you could do is:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"one":@"1",@"two":@"2"};

for (NSString* key in [myDict allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, myDict[key]);
}
```